# MFC: how to clear recent file list of SDI app?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

Is there a way to clear the recent file list under the File menu? I try to do something with `m_pRecentFileList` but so far no success yet with error:

> C2027: use of undefined type `CRecentFileList`.

```
BOOL CMRCApp::InitInstance()
{
    ...

    while (m_pRecentFileList->GetSize() > 0)
        m_pRecentFileList->Remove(0);  // no Clear function ??

    return TRUE;
}
```

#### Update

After fixing the compilation error, the `while` loop becomes infinite. The `Remove(...)` function doesn't seem to decrement the list.

Comment: `#include <afxadv.h>` per [CRecentFileList Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/crecentfilelist-class?view=vs-2019).

Comment: @dxiv You beat me to it! I was writing a (possibly unnecessary) answer when you posted your comment. I was going to make it more complex, but the OP's code is essentially correct, so I typed a lot of code in, then realized it was not required. (Honour would dictate that, if you post an answer, I should remove mine!)

Comment: @AdrianMole No worry, I +1'd your answer and would expect the OP to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has the right idea! However, to access the `m_pRecentFileList` member's functions, you have to include the `afxadv.h` header file.

*EDIT: As the `Remove(0)` call doesn't seem to alter the value returned by `GetSize()` (as you have noted in the comments), you should keep track of the list's size yourself.*

Something like this would do the trick:

```cpp
#include <afxadv.h> // For the definition of the CRecentFileList class
//...
void CMRCApp::ClearRFL()
{
    int nRFL = m_pRecentFileList->GetSize();
    while (nRFL > 0) m_pRecentFileList->Remove(--nRFL);
    return;
}
```

Also, be sure to put the call to this function (or it's code) at (or very near) the end of your `InitInstance` override (and certainly after the base class `InitInstance` has been called) so that the framework has actually finished loading the MRU. You should also make sure it comes after any explicit call to `LoadStdProfileSettings()`.

Comment: It ends up infinite loop. After Remove(...), the size does not seem to decrement. Check my new edit. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user180574 See edit - I checked it in one of my 'working' apps and it does the trick.